# X11 MotionNotify events don't show up in a seperate shared library?

Tags: c++, x11

I have two shared libraries: one for setting up windows and rendering to them with opengl, and another seperate input library which gathers mouse and keyboard input for the windows which are created in the rendering library.

Now, I can recieve events properly in the rendering library, such as mouse, keyboard, and other events. I can also get key events in the input library, but the mouse events aren't sent. I have a debug output set up which shows the return value of `XPending()` ie. the number of events in the queue, and on the rendering library it shows a bunch of events. Moving the mouse or clicking it causes more events to queue up. In the input library I also have that debug output. The keyboard shows only 1 event when a key is pressed/released, and zero otherwise. The mouse however always shows zero events.

To get my X window handle, I have a function in my window class which returns a 64 bit integer which is big enough to contain a window handle on X11 and Windows (since my libraries are cross-platform). In the input library I cast that back to an X window handle. To get my X display, I call `XOpenDisplay(0)` in the mouse/keyboard constructor.

So why do I get mouse events in my rendering library, but not in my input library?

EDIT: [Here](https://gist.github.com/1742147) is source code which shows the problem (~200 lines of code)

Comment: Is there any chance that you could distill the essence of the problem down to two 30-line programs?

Answer (score 0):

Having multiple Display open makes things tricky. In this case you have multiple separate sockets and command/event streams to the X server, and you appear to the X server to be multiple different applications (different clients).

Ordering of request processing and events is not defined across two different connections. For example, if the user presses a key then moves the mouse, you will get those in that order on the *same* Display, but in either order on two different Display.

One trick in a setup like this is that any X resources (windows, GCs, etc.) you create on one display will NOT necessarily be visible to the other display connection until you XSync(). This is because IDs are created client-side and then later flushed to the X server. XSync() both flushes a resource creation request and ensures that the X server has processed the request. (More precisely: any round-trip request - one that has to wait for a reply - will do this; XSync internally just does an XGetInputFocus() which is an arbitrarily-selected round trip request. So if you know which requests are round trips, you don't have to sync after those.)

Pointer and keyboard grabs are also tricky. A grab locks the pointer or keyboard to a particular connection. So whenever you grab, your other Display will not get events covered by the grab, until you ungrab.

XGrabServer() is even trickier; this request asks the X server to stop processing requests and sending events for all displays except the one with the server grab. So if one of your Display grabs the server, any attempt to use the other one will probably lock up your program.

Finally, your input masks (here passed to XCreateWindow, but see XSelectInput) are per-display-connection. I think this may be your actual problem; some of your Display haven't asked for the needed events on the window. But I didn't verify this.

I'd suggest calling XOpenDisplay() one time then pass the single display to your various other code. It will make things much less tricky and maybe even solve the problem.